# bootstrap styles are not applying after I included them in a simple HTML page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

My html isn't linking to the bootstrap CSS. I downloaded bootstrap and copied the CSS, FONTS, and JS folders to a project folder. I created and index.html file in the same folder containing the CSS, FONTS, and JS. Here is the html.

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
                    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
                    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
                    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
                    <script src="js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                   <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        </head>
    <body>
        <div class="col-lg-5 success" >login form</div>
     <form action="logins.php" method="post" >
         user name : <input type="text" name="uname" required >
    password:<input type="password" name="pass" required >
    <input type="submit" value="login">
    </form>
        <a href="regist.php">please register</a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: On first, bootstrap.css and bootstrap.min.css are same file, .min are minified file, it's the same for bootstrap.js and bootstrap.min.js

Comment: Checkout @hometoast's answer. You definitely need to fix that. If you still don't see the styles, in chrome, open a developer console, and refresh the page. See if you get and errors there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only include `bootstrap.js` or `bootstrap.min.js`, but not both. Same goes for the .css file. Either the .css or the .min.css file, not both.

bootstrap.js requires jquery. Don't forget that as well.

```
<head>
   <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
   <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
   <script src="js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: i am including only bootstrap.min.js. and bootstrap.css but not working

Comment: Then I suggest you do what @spundun recommended: open the developer console (F12 for IE9+) and see if it reports javascript errors.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)  this error occures in console

Comment: Is the 403 error occurring on the bootstrap css file?  Then thats your problem.  403 indicates a problem with file permissions.

Comment: "not working" is REALLY hard for the rest of the world to help you with. If you're still getting a 403, in the console, find out WHAT resource is failing. Go from there.